# Why does the 'else' statement execute even though the 'if' was true?

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.8

I can't work out why the output is evaluating to "?" instead of to int(3). Could someone please explain this? Running Python 3.8.

```
number1=3
number2=1
operator="*"
if operator =="+":
    answer=number1+number2
if operator =="-":
    answer=number1-number2
if operator =="*":
    answer=number1*number2
if operator =="/":
    answer=number1/number2
else:
    answer="?"
print(answer)
```

I tried the search function but could not find anything that resolved my issue. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The else only applies to `if operator =="/":`, you need to use `elif`

Answer (score 3):

You run a few `if` in a row. The `else` statement is part of the last `if` and is not effective in the prev `ifs`. Try this -

```
if operator =="+":
    answer=number1+number2
elif operator =="-":
    answer=number1-number2
elif operator =="*":
    answer=number1*number2
elif operator =="/":
    answer=number1/number2
else:
    answer="?"
```

Answer (score 1):

The last else statement will be run while `operator != "/"`。 You should use `elif` statement

Right way:

```py
number1=3
number2=1
operator="*"
if operator =="+":
    answer=number1+number2
elif operator =="-":
    answer=number1-number2
elif operator =="*":
    answer=number1*number2
elif operator =="/":
    answer=number1/number2
else:
    answer="?"
print(answer)
```